# cURL error (60) SSL certificate problem

Tags: feeds

On my local Wamp, I am trying to import feeds using the Feeds and import.io modules.

Each time I get the following error:

> cURL error (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed for https://api.import.io/store/connector

The error doesn't occur on my hosted environment.

I have looked HTTPS and [SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed, CA is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok), and tried adding my php.ini files located in:

- C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0
- C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11

Adding `curl.cainfo = "C:/wamp/www/dev/curl/cacert.pem"` doesn't get any result.

Answer (score 1):

Locally you can disable the error by adding this to your curl options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

This forces curl to not verify your local cert.

Comment: Thanks!

Still after some searching it is not clear to me where to add these curl options.

Should that be in my php.ini files. That is on locations as described in my question?

Comment: That line of code would be in your php file, it's a run time line of code.

Comment: In my php.ini i have placed your line under:
extension=php_curl.dll

However receiving this fatal error:
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY' in C:\wamp\www\dev\includes\database\mysql\database.inc on line 46